# Eclipse C exclude header file in build configuration

Tags: c++, eclipse, header-files, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse, using CDT.

Is there a quick way to have two identical build configurations, but in one configuration to use only src/foo.h and in the other only src/bar/foo.h ?

The src/ dir has lots of other header files, and I am optimistically hoping to not have to add them all one by one when only one file is actually different.

I also don't really want to move either of the files or modify them, since they are not libraries or directory structures that I have written myself. 
(If i really have to, then I guess I have to sort it out)

I suppose some sort of "exclude" list would be ideal. Does that exist?

Comment: What do you mean, "only one file is actually different" ? What are those header files, is this from an external library?

Comment: Yes, these are from external libraries. I have two build configurations. The both use all the same library files. Except one file needs to be not included in one of the builds, and instead anther file in another path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a macro which tells you which build configuration your are building for and then use that to decide which file to include.

Right-click on your project, choose Properties. Then in the dialog which pops up choose C/C++ Build, then Settings. You should end up in a view which let's you define preprocessor definitions (macros).

Then in your header file either do the following:

```
#ifndef MY_MACRO

// contents of header file only available when MY_MACRO is NOT defined    

#endif
```

Or you can (and should probably) do at the point of inclusion instead, so for this is a source file:

```
#ifdef MY_MACRO
#  include "bar.h"
#else
#  include "foo/bar.h"
#endif
```

If you include the header file from several source files and do not want to copy the above-mentioned lines you can add another header which does the inclusion for you by just copy-pasting the lines above and then including that header everywhere.

Comment: Thanks!. looks like that worked. I couldn't find any "macro", so I just put it as a "symbol" under c/c++ General -> Paths and symbols